# I am using VS2022 Community Preview 17.1.0. After I installed the .NET Core 3.1.415 SDK, I don't see the Blank Solution Template anymore

Tags: .net-core-3.1, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to do some at-home training for my job.  I'm going thru various tutorials and everything was just fine.  I could find and use the Blank Solution Template successfully.  Then I installed the .NET Core 3.1.415 SDK so that my code examples would match exactly to what my team is utilizing at work.  Suddenly, I am no longer able to find the Blank Solution Template.

***Screenshot of the problem:***

[image]

Comment: I can see the "Blank Solution" template after upgrading to latest (17.4.0) vs2022 version.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your installation by making sure the "Additional project template" checkbox is checked as shown here:

[image]